# Error while starting cmus "Home directory not accessible: Permission denied"

Tags: sound, permissions, pulseaudio, cmus

I recently did an install on cmus, following the instructions on
https://www.tecmint.com/install-cmus-music-player-in-linux/
which specifies to start it using `sudo cmus` in which I received the output:

```
rene@rene:~$ sudo cmus
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
```

I tried running it without the sudo and it seems like it might actually be required

```
cmus: error: opening `/home/rene/.config/cmus': Permission denied
```

---

After some searching, I think that might problem might have to do with the pulseaudio 10.0. I've looked through the solution on [pulseaudio not working : "Home directory not accessible: Permission denied"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338382/pulseaudio-not-working-home-directory-not-accessible-permission-denied) but the solutions do not seem to work for me.

Here is my output for `pulseaudio --dump-conf`

```
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = 
log-level = notice
resample-method = auto
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
lfe-crossover-freq = 0
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 4
default-fragment-size-msec = 25
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 200000
```

Comment: Run `ls -al  /home/rene/.config/cmus` and lets see who owns the folders involved.

Comment: I get a permission denied when I try to run it without sudo
`ls: cannot open directory '/home/rene/.config/cmus': Permission denied`

With sudo I get the following output 
`total 8 drwx------  2 root root 4096 Apr 23 12:02 . drwx------ 40 rene rene 4096 Apr 23 13:41 .. srwxr-xr-x  1 root root    0 Apr 23 12:02 socket`

Comment: The sudo part had changed the ownership, so reverse it with `sudo chown -R rene.rene ~/.config/cmus` then launch it with just `cmus`

Answer (score 2):

The instructions use `sudo apt..` to install cmus, but I think its an error in teh document to use `sudo` (which elevates privileges) to run it.

Just use `cmus` to use cmus.

Answer (score -1):

First Uninstall cmus
which cmus
rm -rf /location/of/cmus
or
sudo apt remove cmus
or
brew remove cmus
then
sudo su
sudo apt install cmus
sudo su "your user"
cmus

Comment: or you can use this simple answer: sudo chown -R user:user $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR