# Pulseaudio not working, daemon already running and no permission for home folder

Tags: sound, permissions, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, and the sound "suddenly" stopped working. I have been playing around with the issue for some time, so it's possible that I added another layer of problems on top of the original one. The situation at the moment is the following:

`pulseaudio` produces

`E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
 E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.`

Running it as `sudo pulseaudio`:

`E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied`

Then, I tried the solution proposed by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338382/pulseaudio-not-working-home-directory-not-accessible-permission-denied) to fix the accessibility problem of the home directory:

`sudo chown -R giovanni:giovanni /home/giovanni`

but with no apparent effect. Running `pavucontrol` works fine.

The output of `pulseaudio -vvvvv` is as following:

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 8.0
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 4.4.0-130-generic #156-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 08:53:28 UTC 2018
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 5557250d9a584b4babf69038dc518427.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is c2.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/giovanni/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

I tried to remove and reinstall *pulseaudio* (several times) but with no success. Also, I verified that there's no *pulseaudio* file in:

`~/.config/autostart/`

There are no files in:

`/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/pulseaudio`
`/etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio-kde.desktop`

There is a file in:

`/etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio.desktop`

I would be grateful for any suggestions on what to check or how to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Running/

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, none of the top Google results helped, and I finally found a solution that worked: make sure your user is in the `audio` group.

I added mine with the following command:

```
sudo addgroup $USER audio
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This wasn't the problem in my case, as I already was a member of 'audio'.

Comment: This was the case for me

Comment: The user group `audio` is unlikely to be a fix, at least with modern Ubuntu - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups#Pre-systemd_groups which notes that it's used for accessing device files pre-systemd. More details at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/ particularly 71-seat.rules and 73-seat-late.rules that ship with systemd (thanks buhman from #pulseaudio IRC)

Comment: @BenCreasy On the contrary, this ended up fixing a pulseaudio issue that I've been trying to fix for a month and a half now on 19.10.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues:

1. sound suddenly stopped
2. not able to change output and input devices
3. not recognized newly added sound adaptor
4. none working microphone
5. none working headphone

and found out that for some reasons multiple `pulseaudio` servers were running by executing `ps x | grep pulseaudio`. The following steps solved the problem:

1. Kill all the instances with `killall pulseaudio`.
2. Start the daemone again with `pulseaudio`.

After that it worked again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Please don't add the things that *didn't work* to the answer, but the essential parts that *did work!*  And also: **Keep up the good work! :-)**

Comment: `killall pulseaudio` and it's still there in `ps`

Comment: it's being launched by some other process/service. works fine apparently. i just can't use the pulseaudio command without error

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue where the attached USB audio device just played on 4 of the 8 output channels after update from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. The pulseaudio log was

> ```
> E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
> E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
> ```

Deleting the files in `~/.config/pulse` and restarting the machine solves the issue

Comment: absolute legend.

Answer (score 1):

What did work for me :

Pulseaudio configuration's files in

> ~/.config/pulse

were like

> 589187e8155f40638e8344f0f9b0ab3c-*

Therefore I deleted them then I did

> cp /etc/pulse/* ~/.config/pulse/

It works !